# What would the structure of a biological thermocouple be?

Tags: biology, anatomy, biochemistry, electricity, thermodynamics

For reference: a [thermocouple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple) is a device that converts heat to electricity.

What would an organic, naturally-evolved one that's part of a biological organism look like in terms of structure?

Comment: I'm inclined to VTC for missing details. Thermocouples operate by producing a voltage (potential difference) based on the presence of a thermal difference. That means that your organ must detect two temperatures and have a pair of electrical outputs (anode & cathode). Please explain where the two thermal inputs are coming from and where the electrical outputs are going, otherwise we're making assumptions (opinions, VTC...) about the structure you're asking for.

Comment: Before you answer, it's *incredibly important* that you understand that thermocouples do ***not*** convert heat into electricity. It's not that simple. They induce current flow based on the presence of a thermal difference in a similar way that a generator induces current flow based on the presence of a magnetic difference. If you can't explain where the two thermal references are, the question is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thermocouples require a thermal gradient, they turn the flow of heat from a hotter to a cooler region of the device into a voltage difference. On the other hand [biological electrical generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_organ_(biology)) work on the basis of pumping charged ions to produce a static charge of freed electrons. To mesh the two systems you need cells that are structurally similar to [chloroplastic organelles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroplast) but tuned to [infrared radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared) instead of visible light. These cells will absorb heat and use that energy, and carbon and water in correct proportion to create [glucose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose) that can then be used to fuel electrocytes. A creature exploited this energy pathway as its primary metabolic solution is going to be an [ectotherm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectotherm) potentially with a large reactive surface area depending on the source situation. An exothermic creature using this as a secondary pathway is probably not going to evolve in the first place because the creature will spend less energy fueling it's electrocytes directly than by a roundabout secondary reaction path.

Answer (score 1):

A thermocouple produces a voltage, not a current. As said by the very page you quote

> A thermocouple is an electrical device consisting of two dissimilar electrical conductors forming an electrical junction. A thermocouple produces a temperature-dependent voltage as a result of the Seebeck effect

The only conductors a living organism has are either ion channels or saline solutions, so it's likely that a biological thermocouple will use either of them, as long as they can have a suitable energy level difference.

Comment: This isn't the way electricity works. Ohm's Law: V=IR, all the device needs to produce current is the presence of a resistance between its anode and cathode. The only way to have a voltage without a current is to apply an infinitely large resistance (in which case the presence of the voltage is irrelevant).